# Some questions about reduction of elliptic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $E \rightarrow S$ be an elliptic curve (i.e, a smooth proper curve of genus 1).

If $S = \text{Spec (K)}$ where $K$ is a local field, the usual way of doing a reduction at a prime $\mathfrak{p} = (\pi)$ is by reducing the defining equation of the elliptic curve modulo $\pi$ or, equivalently, by finding the Néron model of $E$, namely $\tilde{E} \rightarrow \text{Spec} (\mathcal{O}_K)$ and define $\tilde{E}_{\kappa(\mathfrak{p})} \rightarrow \text{Spec} (\kappa(\mathfrak{p}))$ as the reduction in the prime $\mathfrak{p}$. In the case of $K$ a global field, the same process applies when completing in the prime $\mathfrak{p}$ and reducing to the case of a local field.

And, now comes the questions:

1) It's natural to do another process. Suppose $K$ is a global field. If $\tilde{E} \rightarrow \text{Spec} (\mathcal{O}_K)$ is the Néron model, then I could simply define $\tilde{E}_{\kappa(\mathfrak{p})} \rightarrow \text{Spec} (\kappa(\mathfrak{p}))$ as the reduction, where the pullback is given by the inclusion of a point at $\mathfrak{p}$. Or I could define the reduction by using the Néron model over $\mathcal{O}_{K, \mathfrak{p}}$ and defining the reduction as the fiber over $\mathfrak{p}$. Are these constructions equivalent?

2) It's known that if the reduction is bad, then it's multiplicative or additive. In these cases, respectively, $E_{nonsing} \cong \mathbb{G}_m$ and $E_{nonsing} \cong \mathbb{G}_a$. Is it possible to prove such isomorphisms in a more scheme-theoretical way? In Silverman's book, for instance, the proof uses the defining equation of $E$.

3)Is there a more scheme-theoretical way of defining what's a split multiplicative reduction?

4)If $S$ is an arbitrary scheme and viewing $E \rightarrow S$ as a deformation of elliptic curves, is it possible to define a reduction of this family at some prime under certain suitable conditions? For instance, if the residue field is always the same ($\kappa (s)$ is always the same for each $s \in S$), then it's possible to find the Néron model of each fiber $E_s \rightarrow \text{Spec} (\kappa (s))$ and reduce at a given prime $\mathfrak{p}$ of $\mathcal{O}_{\kappa (s)}$, however I can't see any reasonable way to glue everything (such that the morphism to the base is at least flat).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes to 1). The Neron model is unique. In 2), the isomorphisms you write are only true over the algebraic closure. Have a look at  Chapter 10 of Liu's book for more "scheme-theoretic" proofs. The same chapter also answers 3). Indeed, split multiplicative is the same as split semi-stable (+ singular). I don't completely understand 4). If $E\to S$ is an elliptic curve (so flat in particular) over a scheme $S$, then for all $s$ in $S$ the fibre $E_s$ is an elliptic curve. This is the reduction of $E/S$ at $s$.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Thanks for your response. How can you conclude 1) by just saying that the Néron model is unique? To simplify let's assume $K = \mathbb{Q}$. Note that in my alternative definition, $\tilde{E} \rightarrow \text{Spec} (\mathbb{Z}_{( p )})$, where $\mathbb{Z}_{( p )}$ is the localization at $( p )$ and not over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (p-adic numbers). I could ask for the Néron model over $\mathbb{Z}$ too. I will edit my question to clarify this. About 3) I want to reduce each $E_s \rightarrow \text{Spec} (\kappa(s))$ and then glue everything.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Sorry I mistyped my comment. It should be "About 4), I want to reduce ..."

Comment: Have a look at Proposition 1.2.4 in the book "Neron models" by Bosch et al. This proposition implies that, if $N$ is the Neron model of the elliptic curve $E$ over $\mathbb Q$, then $N_{\mathbb Z_{(p)}}$ is the Neron model of $E$ over $\mathbb Z_{(p)}$. I agree that the unicity is not all you need here. To prove that Proposition you need to use limit arguments and reduce to the statement that "the Neron model commutes with etale base-change".

Comment: I still don't understand 4. Is $E\to S$ an elliptic curve or is only its generic fibre an elliptic curve? Also, what do you mean by finding the Neron model of $E_s \to Spec(k(s))$? To speak of a model for $X/k$ over a scheme $S$, we usually ask $k$ to be function field of this scheme $S$. Are you asking about whether an elliptic curve $E\to S$ is uniquely determined by its generic fibre? In that case, the answer is positive if $S$ is integral noetherian and regular.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar $E \rightarrow S$ is an elliptic curve over an arbitrary scheme $S$. About the fibers, let's simplify to the case $\kappa (s) \cong K$, where $K$ is a global field. Under these assumptions, is it possible to reduce each $E_s \rightarrow \text{Spec} (K)$ and then glue everything to a curve over $S$ with fibers the reduction of $E_s$.

Comment: Consider an elliptic curve $E \to \mathbb A^1_{\mathbb Q} - \{0,1\}$. Let $s$ be a rational point of the base. Then $E_s$ is an elliptic curve over $\mathbb Q$. What does it mean to "reduce $E_s$" in this case? And do you mean by "glueing everything to a curve over $S$"? Isn't $E\to S$ already the object you need?

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Reduce $E_s$ means reducing $E_s \rightarrow \text{Spec (Q)}$ at a fixed prime $p$. After reducing at $p$, call $\tilde{E_s} \rightarrow \text{Spec} (\mathbb{Z}/(p))$ the reduction of $E_s$, is it possible to define a curve over $S = \mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{Q}}$ such that the fiber at $s$ is isomorphic to  $\tilde{E_s}$? In other words, I have a deformation of elliptic curves and I want to define a reduction of a family of elliptic curves in a given prime.

Comment: Any elliptic curve $E$ over a dense open $U \subset \mathbb A^1_{\mathbb Q}$ extends to an elliptic curve over a dense open $\mathcal U \subset \mathbb A^1_{\mathbb Z}$.  That should help you do what you want for large $p$. You won't find a curve over $S$ whose fiber at $s$ is isomorphic to $\tilde{E}_s$ simply because $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb F_p$ are not isomorphic...

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Well, actually I don't need to maintain $S$, I just want to keep the underlying topological space of $S$. To clarify myself, what I really want is some method to reduce (in a given prime) modular curves $X_0 (N)/_{\mathbb{Q}}$. In the simplest case , there is no level structure, so it's just the (fine) moduli space of elliptic curves. Any idea on how to proceed in this case?

Comment: Seems like you're asking about the reduction of $X_0(n)$. Have a look at Katz-Mazur's book Arithmetic moduli of elliptic curves and Brian Conrad's article in J. inst. Jussieu with a similar title.